# Pytest with xdist takes 16x longer, regardless of number of workers

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

I've just added pytest to an existing Django project - all unit tests are using Django's `unittest` subclasses, etc. We use an SQLite in-memory database for tests.

- `manage.py test` takes rougly 80 seconds on our test suite
- `py.test` takes the same
- `py.test -n1` (or `-n4`, or anything like that) takes roughly 1280 seconds.

I would expect an overhead to support the distribution, but obviously with `-n4`, it should be approximately 3-4 times faster on a large-ish test suite.

Findings...

I've so far traced the issue down to database access. The tests run quickly until they *first* hit the database, but at the first `.save()` call on a Django model, *that* test will be incredibly slow.

After some profiling on the workers, it *looks* like they are spending a lot of time waiting on locks, but I have no idea if that's a reliable finding or not.

I wondered if there was some sort of locking on the database, it was suggested to me that the in-memory SQLite database might be a memory mapped file, and that locking might be happening on that between the workers, but apparently each call to open an in-memory database with SQLite will return a completely separate instance.

---

As it stands, I've probably spent 5+ hours on this so far, and spoken at length to colleagues and others about this, and not yet found the issue. I have not been able to reproduce on a separate codebase.

- What kind of things might cause this?
- What more could I do to further track down the issue?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: What are the specifications of your target system and, have you enabled the shared cache?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I don't think the specs of the machine are important, we can reproduce the same execution time ratios on different machines. As for the cache, I'm not familiar with it, is that pytest-cache? That seems to deal with *betwee* test runs, not within a test run?

Comment: No, not pytest-cache - I am talking about the SQLite [shared cache](https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid ah, thanks for the clarification, I wasn't aware of this. Reading the docs, it looks like this will be disabled  
> "*shared cache is always disable for in-memory databases if the unadorned name ":memory:" is used to open the database*"